# What specifically can an OP see after close votes have been cast but before an item is put on hold?

Tags: support, vote-to-close

Update: Thanks to comment from @Servy, received link to this [help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes) from the Privileges section which answers the question except for question of detail (e.g. off-topic sub-reasons) and, if detail not present, rationale. Thanks to help from @Mat, confirmed that off-topic detail is not provided. So, only thing missing at this point is design rationale for not providing the off-topic detail.

I've found [Display close votes for all users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34616/display-close-votes-for-all-users) which, title notwithstanding, seems to indicate by virtue of the comments and *status completed* tag that votes were made visible for the OP only at some point, but doesn't provide specifics.

[Closevoting in progress should be visible to newcomers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72704/closevoting-in-progress-should-be-visible-to-newcomers) remains open, however.

I've seen other questions (which I can't find now) which indicate the presence of something like `close (2/5)`, but it's not clear whether you can click through to see the vote reasons or any other information.

I couldn't find any information on this in the formal "help" section.

While I'll take whatever information I can get, if the specific close reasons are not made available to the op, I'd be interested in understanding the rationale why (e.g. keeping it simple, etc.). (NOTICE: In this question, I am not proposing or requesting that the specific close reasons be made available. Really. I'm just trying to understand design rationale.)

I apologize if this information is already available somewhere. I spent about twenty minutes trying to research this.

Comment: See [this help page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes)

Comment: @Servy Thank you. Is the "off topic" detail given or are all "off topic" votes bundled for purpose of this summary?  Also, since I had such a hard time finding this, do you know if this page is linked to from anywhere else on the site?

Comment: Not sure; I haven't asked a question that had closed votes on it while in that particular reputation range (or ever, for that matter).  Where else do you think that page *should* be linked from?  You can access the index of privileges from either your profile, or the help center, and are linked to it in the notification you get when you earn a new privilege.

Comment: I think anything significant related to question workflow ought to be covered under the "Asking" section of the help. And I consider the process of getting feedback through close votes to be a fundamental part of the "asking" workflow. I realize that it's a challenge documenting features that require particular rep levels and I understand that the information is provided at the point the user obtains that privilege. Now that you remind me, I do vaguely remember reading this information when I passed that threshold, but I was looking for it now. :-)

Comment: I could cast a close vote here if you want, but I'm pretty sure you see the same dialog as when voting to close after you've got >3k.

Comment: @Mat You had be worried there for a minute - I'm so paranoid about downvotes and close votes at this point! ;-)  Anyway, yeah, if you wouldn't mind casting an off-topic close vote, I'd appreciate it. And you can do it on this question here in MSO, since I don't think there's any difference between SO/MSO or 250/3000

Comment: My pleasure :-) Cast a "cannot be reproduced" vote.

Comment: @Mat Yep, no off-topic detail.  Thanks!

Comment: D'you want to take a screenshot? (I'll retract it otherwise)

Comment: No, I think we're ok without it (and frankly, I haven't been able to get the copy/paste to work when inserting images). Thanks again.

Comment: Related (maybe only peripherally): [Please automatically include text covering site specific close reasons in the help center](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/186514)

Comment: @Mat Are you still there?  I just saw the off-topic close detail on SO (where I have >3k) for a pre-on-hold question from another user and I wanted to do the same test we did with you before here on MSO in case I misunderstood the UI.

Comment: Mat and Peter, is it still possible to get that screenshot? It would be a very useful reference for this and all sites to know what a <3k user sees when their question has closevotes pending.

Comment: @episanty If you'll go ahead and close-vote this question with off-topic, I'll capture the screen.